how do I add Google Drive and MS drive
I am a newbie to Linux. I have used it on and off for years but never for very long. With all the BS stuff MS is doing these days I want to gave it a go again and hopefully stick with it.
One thing I must have is access to google drive. Can someone point me to simple directions to do this. I did searched but nothing has worked so far, telling me to do things I just couldn't fine in my install of Linux. Also the answers that were suggested didn't seem to be what I was looking for.
P.S. I tried this and it didn't work.
https://technastic.com/mount-google-drive-on-ubuntu/

You didn't say which version of Ubuntu nor which parts of the instructions you followed didn't work - perhaps it was the command sudo apt install google-drive-ocamlfuse. In Ubuntu 22.04 go to settings -> Online Accounts and select the cloud services you are interested in (Google and Microsoft i n your case).

If you want basic access to Google Drive (e.g. you are just going to view/copy files) then use the Ubuntu online accounts method as someone already said. If you want to do anything more complex with Google Drive like run backups to it or rsync scripts then you will need to use google-drive-ocamlfuse. But see the instructions on the github pages as that article you linked now seems to be out of date: https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse

Google stopped supporting Ocamlfuse.
Rclone is a tool to manage data in the cloud efficiently and securely on Linux systems
Open a terminal.
Run in it:
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install rclone

Configure the application with the following command in the same terminal:
   rclone config

Select the option to add a new remote, select “n” and press Enter.
Choose a name to be used to refer to your Google Drive connection in rclone, for example Gdrive
Select the type of storage you will use, Google Drive corresponds to drive (13) and press Enter.
Configure the Google Drive application, follow the instructions that appear in the terminal to obtain the authorization token, which will allow you to access your Google Drive from rclone.
Select the default configuration settings, which are suitable.
Once the configuration is complete, it will show you a summary of your options, if everything is correct, confirm the configuration.
Create the directory where to mount Google-drive, for example ~/gdrive, by running in the terminal
   mkdir gdrive
   

To access Google-drive, you must run the following command in a terminal:
   rclone mount Gdrive: ~/google-drive &
   

You can create a script to run this command when you start your computer and always have google-drive mounted on your system, if you want. But this is another topic to investigate in the forum.
For One Drive, you can check this site:
https://miguelmenendez.es/es/blog/2022/montar-microsoft-onedrive-gnu-linux-rclone/

Thanks, will give it a try.
